# wall bounce in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm writing a game for unity and I encountered a problem, I need the ball to bounce off the walls all the time without losing speed, my ball crashes into the wall and stays in it, here is the code

I tried to solve this problem through gpt chat and articles and YouTube videos on YouTube`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private Vector3 lastVelocity;
    private Vector3 goalVelocity;


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        lastVelocity = rb.velocity;
        rb.velocity = goalVelocity;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
        {
            Vector3 reflection = Vector3.Reflect(lastVelocity, collision.contacts[0].normal);
            rb.velocity = reflection.normalized * speed;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (rb == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Rigidbody component not found!");
            return;
        }
        goalVelocity = rb.velocity;
        Vector3 randomDirection = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1f, 1f), 0f, Random.Range(-1f, 1f)).normalized;
        rb.AddForce(randomDirection * speed, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could skip the normalization and just do this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
    {
        Vector3 reflection = Vector3.Reflect(lastVelocity, collision.contacts[0].normal);
        rb.velocity = reflection;
    }
}
```

This will probably fix the issue because I think you set `speed` to zero (it's not declared in your code).

You could also just give the wall a physics material with bounce set to 1. That would be easier than all that code, though it would make anything else bounce off the wall too.

EDIT: The reason you can skip the normalization part is because normalizing a vector means dividing it by its magnitude, and your speed is the magnitute of your velocity. You're dividing it by a number and then multiplying it by that same number again (or at least attempting to, if `speed` really is zero).

Comment: I indicated the speed, I probably missed the code when I sent it.
I didn’t understand how to add bounce to the walls, because when I click material.
 material none (physics material) and I can’t add anything there.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through physics materials as well.

Create a Physic material in project. Then just simply add that to any physics component (Rigidbody, or Collider).

On Physics material you can see the friction. Which can make it ideal.